# How to Send React Native Events to JavaScript from JavaScript

Tags: ios, react-native

Using React Native, I can dispatch events from a native module according to the [official React Native Native Modules documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios#sending-events-to-javascript). But how can I dispatch events from JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/nativemodulesios.html#sending-events-to-javascript

I can not understand your question correctly !!

> **Provide code!**

Maybe you are looking something like this:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

var server = new EventEmitter();

server.on('foo', function() {
  console.log('got foo');
});

server.emit('foo');
```

Check this pull:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/918

Comment: My question is: How to do 'eventDispatcher sendAppEventWithName' in Javascript?

Comment: with some update for 2020 the code will be something like this: import {DeviceEventEmitter} from 'react-native'; DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('logout', this.showLogout); DeviceEventEmitter.emit("logout");

Answer (score 4):

You can send React Native events from JavaScript like so:

```
import { NativeEventEmitter, NativeModules } from "react-native";

const nativeEventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(NativeModules.Emitter);
nativeEventEmitter.emit("Event Name");
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for iOS 
```Invariant Violation: `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument., js engine: hermes```